# Serializer using Normalizer returns nothing when using setCircularReferenceHandler

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, php-7.1, symfony-3.3

### Question:

Why does my response return "blank" when I set the `setCircularReferenceHandler` callback?

**EDIT:**

Would appear that it returns nothing, but does set the header to `500 Internal Server Error`. This is confusing as Symfony should send some kind of error response concerning the error?

I wrapped `$json = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');` in a try/catch but no explicit error is thrown so nothing is caught. Any ideas would be really helpful.

### Context:

When querying for an Entity Media I get a blank response. Entity Media is mapped (with Doctrine) to Entity Author. As they are linked, indefinite loops can occur when trying to serialize.

I had hoped that using the Circular Reference Handler I could avoid just that, but it's not working.

### Error:

This is the error I'm getting when I'm **NOT** setting the Circular Reference Handler:

> A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class "Proxies__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Author\Author" (configured limit: 1) (500 Internal Server Error)

Now this error is ***completely expected***, as my Entity Author points back to the Entity Media when originally querying for a Media ( `Media -> Author -> Media` )

```
   class Author implements JsonSerializable {

     //Properties, Getters and setters here

     /**
     * Specify data which should be serialized to JSON
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php
     * @return mixed data which can be serialized by <b>json_encode</b>,
     * which is a value of any type other than a resource.
     * @since 5.4.0
     */
    function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            "title"     => $this->getTitle(),
            "id"        => $this->getId(),
            "firstname" => $this->getFirstname(),
            "lastname"  => $this->getLastname(),

            //This is the problem right here. Circular reference.
            "medias"    => $this->getAuthorsMedia()->map(function($object){
                return $object->getMedia();
            })
        ];
    }
  }
```

### What I've tried:

My Entities implement `JsonSerializable` interface so I define what attributes are returned (Which is what `JsonSerializeNormalizer` requires). This works completely ***when I remove the "medias" property in the Author's class***, ***everything works***.

Here is how I use my serliazer with my normalizer.

```
/**
 * @Route("/media")
 * Class MediaController
 * @package BackBundle\Controller\Media
 */
class MediaController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function listAction(){
        /** @var MediaService $mediaS */
        $mediaS= $this->get("app.media");

        /** @var array $data */
        $data = $mediaS->getAll();
        $normalizer = new JsonSerializableNormalizer();
        $normalizer->setCircularReferenceLimit(1);
        $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function($object){
            return $object->getId();
        });
        $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [new JsonEncoder()]);

        $json = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

        return new Response($json);
    }

}
```

[Github issue opened](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/24121)

Comment: Did you try adding metadata and enabling the `enable_max_depth` setting to work around this? See "[Handling Serialization Depth](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-serialization-depth)"

Comment: How many levels deep do you want to serialize?

Comment: `enable_max_depth` is used by anything extending `AbstractObjectNormalizer`. `JsonSerializableNormalizer` inherits directly from `AbstractNormalizer`, and doesn't use that option at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your error, and for me everything worked as expected (see code samples below).

So, **your setCircularReferenceHandler() works fine**.

Maybe try to run my code, and update it with your real entities and data sources step by step, until you see what causes the error.

*Test (instead of your controller):*

```
class SerializerTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $media = new Media();
        $author = new Author();

        $media->setAuthor($author);
        $author->addMedia($media);
        $data = [$media];

        $normalizer = new JsonSerializableNormalizer();
        $normalizer->setCircularReferenceLimit(1);
        $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function($object){
            /** @var Media $object */
            return $object->getId();
        });
        $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [new JsonEncoder()]);

        $json = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

        $this->assertJson($json);
        $this->assertCount(1, json_decode($json));
    }
}
```

*Media entity*

```
class Media implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Author
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="medias")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            "id"        => $this->getId(),
            "author"    => $this->getAuthor(),
        ];
    }
    //todo: here getter and setters, generated by doctrine
}
```

*Author entity*

```
class Author implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Media[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Media", mappedBy="author")
     */
    private $medias;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            "id"        => $this->getId(),
            "medias"    => $this->getMedias(),
        ];
    }
    //todo: here getter and setters, generated by doctrine
}
```